# How to make single select chips in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I needs a group chip like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBMIM.png

Also it should be single select.it means just one item can select and the others should stay deselect just like a radio group.
Any idea will be greate.

Comment: You are not sharing with us the link to the group chip you need. Please review your question content.

Comment: It's worth clarifying what you mean by a Flutter ["chip"](https://material.io/components/chips/flutter)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [simple_chips_input](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_chips_input) package for this.

It has a library called `select_chips_input`. It would suit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it Like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class JustTest extends StatelessWidget {
  List<String> chipList = ["hello", "hi", "How are you"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: chipList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            //do your work here
          },
          child: Chip(label: Text(chipList[index]))),
    );
  }
}
```